# Unable to access the service instance from within an implementation of IDataContractSurrogate

Tags: wcf

this is my first post, and I really have tried hard to find an answer, but am drawing a blank thus far.

My implementation of IDataContractSurrogate creates surrogates for certain 'cached' objects which I maintain (this works fine). What doesn't work is that in order for this system to operate effectively, it needs to access the service instance for some properties of the instance which it is maintaining from the interaction with its client. Also, when my implementation of IDataContractSurrogate works in its 'client mode' it needs access to the properties of the client instance in a similar way. Access to the information from the client and service instance affects how I create my surrogate types (or rather SHOULD do if I can answer this question!)

My service instancing is PerSession and concurrent.

On the server side, calls to GetDataContractType and GetDeserializedObject contain a valid OperationContext.Current from which I can of course retreive the service instance. However on the client side, none of the calls yield an OperationContext.Current. We are still in an operation as I am translating the surrogate types to the data contract types after they have been sent from the server as part of its response to the client request so I would have expected one? Maybe the entire idea of using OperationContext.Current from outside of an Operation invocation is wrong?

So, moving on, and trying to fix this problem I have examined the clientRuntime/dispatchRuntime object which is available when applying my customer behaviour, however that doesn't appear to give me any form of access to the client instance, unless I have a message reference perhaps... and then calling InstanceProvider. However I don't have the message.

Another idea I had was to use IInstanceProvider myself and then maybe build up a dictionary of all the ones which are dished out... but that's no good because I don't appear to have access to any session related piece of information from within my implementation of IDataContractSurrogate to use as a dictionary key.

I had originally implemented my own serializer but thats not what I want. I'm happy with the built in serializer, and changing the objects to special surrogates is *exactly* what I need to do, with the added bonus that every child property comes in for inspection.

I have also looked at applying a service behavior, but that also does not appear to yield a service instance, and also does not let me set a Surrogate implementation property.

I simply do not know how to gain access to the current session/instance from within my implementation IDataContractSurrogate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Sean

Comment: After doing some more digging it turns that that the client instance is available only when an IsInitiating operation is processed. Coupled with sharing any server/client instances between all implementations I  have in part solved this issue. However, there appear to be some concurrency issues with accessing the service which I am still invetigating, and I have yet to perform testing with multiple clients. Any comments still more then welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The short answer is that I implemented IClientMessageFormatter and IDispatchMessageFormatter to accomplish what I needed. Inside SerializeReply I could always access the ServiceInstance as OperationContext.Current is valid. It was more work as I had to implement my own serialization and deserialization, but works flawlessly. The only issue remaining would be that there is no way to get the client proxy which is processing the response, but so far that is not a show stopper for me.